# 名詞 + なだけ: 志望なだけある

Tags: syntax, particle-な, particle-だけ

> 女優志望なだけあって自分の見せ方わかってる感じがした。([source](https://twitter.com/mss_oknw/status/760863386489921537))

> 爆豪君ってヒーロー志望なだけあるよね ([source](https://www.pixiv.net/novel/show.php?id=16019300))

Given that 志望 is a noun, I don't know what な is doing here.

> 私も本日、二次面接通過の返事を頂けたものです！第一志望なだけに、ひとまずすごく嬉しいです！([source](https://career.keipro.net/japan/200604051749016993/))

I would've expected 第一志望だけに without な. I can't seem to find any related/similar questions, and this issue seemingly hasn't been asked before on this site. Nor was I successful in finding a page about this grammar point on the web at large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The な is 連体形 of だ, and as you see, it can be omitted (or replaced by である).

- 女優志望だけあって
- 女優志望**な**だけあって
- （女優志望**である**だけあって)

All of these mean the same. (Except であるだけあって is clumsy; it sounds less so in the last example: 第一志望であるだけに)

--

To me, using な sounds (slightly) more natural, or simply easier when speaking. It possibly has something to do with [だけ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91/#jn-136029) being originally a noun 丈.